# php split string

Tags: php, string, vb6, count, split

hello i have one very NOOB question and i want to know the answer. First my programing language was VB6 and there i could use Split method like in PHP, but main deference is that when i use this code:

```
$page_array = split('12s12d1a351c12a55a', 'a', 0);
echo count($page_array);
```

i get result "1" where i must get result more than 1. so what is wrong? can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are settings your limit to 0, therefore you will retrieve the whole string as 1 line (no splits)
remove the ,0 in your split statement, also it is (delimiter, string) not (string, delimeter) -> php has some backwards commands

try:

$page_array =  split('a', '12s12d1a351c12a55a');
echo count($page_array);

That should produce : 4

Comment: @Shakti Singh Good catch on the deprecated, ironically I use explode all the time, didn't even catch that part of the answer! Kudos!

Comment: why is better using exmplode than split?

Comment: As Shakti mentioned, split is a deprecated function (no longer 'supported' as of PHP 5.3, merely exists for backwards compatibility), explode is essentially the same function.  Also the manual states: it is faster to use explode(), which doesn't incur the overhead of the regular expression engine.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, split() is deprecated. Take a look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php).

Also: you're limiting the results with the last argument.

```
array split ( string $pattern , string $string [, int $limit = -1 ] )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the docs you see that you set the limit to 0:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

```
split ( string $pattern , string $string [, int $limit = -1 ] )
```

the correct way with explode (is better dan split):

```
$page_array = explode('12s12d1a351c12a55a', 'a');
echo count($page_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

> If limit is set, the returned array
>   will contain a maximum of limit
>   elements with the last element
>   containing the whole rest of string.

This is so because you are setting the limit to 0 and not to use [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) it is deprecated try [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead

```
$page_array = explode('a','12s12d1a351c12a55a');
echo count($page_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to check the manual. The PHP manual of [`split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) is useful.

You code should have been: `$page_array = split('a', '12s12d1a351c12a55a');`